# Reference request: graph Laplacian approximation for domains/manifolds

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, laplacian

Is there any reference on solving the heat equation on irregular geometries via creating a mesh and using the graph Laplacian instead of FEM techniques? (Convergence to real solution).

That is to say, given a set of points $\{x_i\}\in\Omega$, with $\Omega$ a domain, what is the Laplacian matrix best approximating the Laplacian operator in $\Omega$ when restricting functions $f\in\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega)$ to the evaluation $f(x_i)\in\mathbb{R}^n$? I imagine each entry $L_{ij}$ should be only a function of the Euclidean distance $d(x_i,x_j)$.

Comment: I think you're looking for a discrete Laplace-Beltrami operator. The graph Laplacian takes only the topology into account. If you have a triangular mesh you can see: http://mobile.rodolphe-vaillant.fr/entry/101/definition-laplacian-matrix-for-triangle-meshes
If you have a more general polygonal mesh there was a paper by Marc Alexa and Warzdetsky. If you don't have a mesh then there are some mesh-free ways to go about this. From your question it looks like you just have a point cloud. But then you speak of "irregular geometries" at the beginning so it is unclear what you are given.

Comment: @lightxbulb that was actually the string I was looking to follow, thanks Laplacian matrix expert

Answer (score 2):

In a plane, you have something that resembles the graph Laplacian in the form of the 5-point stencil. You can derive the 5-point stencil as an approximation of the finite element matrix by using a specific quadrature rule (namely, the 2-dimensional generalization of the trapezoidal rule) to compute the integrals that define the finite element method.

I would suspect that you can apply the same kind of principle on manifolds: Subdivide it into triangles or quadrilaterals, set up the finite element integrals, then approximate these integrals by a quadrature formula that only evaluates the integrand at the node points.